# I want to use the Xdebug profiling in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, xdebug-3

### Environment

- Windows 10 Home
- local
- PHP 7.4
- PhpStorm 2021.2
- Xdebug 3

### Question

I want to profile with Xdebug in my own application.

I made the following settings.

1. php.ini:

```ini
xdebug.mode = profile;
xdebug.start_with_request = trigger;
```

2. I changed the Xdebug helper setting to profiler
3. Press debug button (in PhpStorm)

### Result

The cachegrind file is not created.

How can I create the cachegrind file?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/profiling-with-xdebug.html

Comment: Thank you！
However, I refer to the above site to set it up.
I don't think so…is it possible to do this locally?

Comment: Locally? If I'm getting you correctly: If you want to do this in CLI (Terminal) and not via website -- you can use more appropriate value for `xdebug.start_with_request` or .. use `trigger` but actually use the trigger ENV variable. Just in case: use ["PHP Script"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration-php-script.html) type of Run/Debug Configuration to run PHP scripts from IDE.

Comment: P.S. You will have to use "Run" button and pass any additional config (ENV vars / params) there. If you use "Debug" button then PhpStorm will pass "xdebug.mode = debug" as a parameter that will override your settings.